# Open a WebSite Link which is written in a TextEdit into a Web navigator

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextEdit in my form to write some web site adresse, and I want when I click on a button to open that website (which is written in the TextEdit) into a web navigator.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the URL from the `TextEdit` to `Process.Start`:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

It will open in the default browser.